# Transformers: Labels and logits mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, SpatialDropout1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Add, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

Load the CSV data into a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('/content/Data4.csv')

# Split the data into training and validation sets
train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
train_df = df[:train_size]
val_df = df[train_size:]

# Preprocess the text data
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['input'].values)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
maxlen = 50 # set the maximum sequence length to 50

# Pad the input and output sequences to the same length
X_train = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_df['input'].values), maxlen = maxlen)
X_val = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_df['input'].values), maxlen = maxlen)
y_train = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_df['output'].values), maxlen = maxlen)
y_val = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_df['output'].values), maxlen = maxlen)

emb_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 128, input_length=maxlen)
E_X_t = emb_layer(X_train)
E_X_v = emb_layer(X_val)
E_y_t = emb_layer(y_train)
E_y_v = emb_layer(y_val)



# Conformer model architecture

input_layer = Input(shape=(maxlen))
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 128, input_length = 50)(input_layer)
conv_layer = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(embedding_layer)
conv_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv_layer)
dropout_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(conv_layer)
MHA = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=8, key_dim = 128, value_dim = 128)(dropout_layer, value = dropout_layer)
Masked = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0)(MHA)
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(Masked)
output_layer =tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation = 'relu')(flat)

y_train_reshaped = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=vocab_size)
y_val_reshaped = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_val, num_classes=vocab_size)
X_train_reshaped = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(X_train, num_classes=vocab_size)
X_val_reshaped = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(X_val, num_classes=vocab_size)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.summary()
#Compile the model with an appropriate loss function and optimizer
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Train the model on the training data
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

When  I use the flatten(), then I get the following error
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [64,954] and labels shape [3200]
[[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2655]

Without flatten(), I get the following error
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 50 and 25 for '{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Reshape_2, sparse_categorical_crossentropy/mul_1)' with input shapes: [?,50], [?,25].

Please solve this issue. I have no idea whether the issue is in embedding or with the data.

I tried the reshape method, which gives the 3d data but it gives the error in Conv1D.